# Returns only a single row for multiple same id in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using asp.net MVC 4 and EF 6 to make a message panel where I want to show a list of single threads. If a thread is viewed, user can see all the messages under that specific thread. In DB, each message has the same `thread id` so that, messages can be viewed under a specific thread. So far user can view the messages under a specific thread but the thread lists is showing each message as a thread. Here are my codes,

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult ViewAllThreads(string MsgPanelId)
    {
        var getUser = rentdb.OwnerRegs.Where(a => a.username == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();

        InboxModel allThreads = new InboxModel() { AllMsg = db.MsgToDb.Where(a => a.owner_id == getUser.serial).ToList() };
        ViewBag.OwnerId = getId;

        return View(allThreads);
    }
```

**View**

```
@foreach (var item in Model.AllMsg)
{
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)</td>
            <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.title)</td>
            <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.addedtime)</td>
            <td class="text-center">@Html.EncodedAction("<b>View Thread</b>", "Reply", "Home", new { thread_id = item.thread_id, msg_id = item.serial })</td>
        </tr>
}
```

How can I make a list where messages with same `thread id` will show as a single thread?

### Update

Here is a snap of table design,

[image: table_design]

Comment: **but the thread lists is showing each message as a thread** Because you are querying all the messages, not the threads. See this part `db.MsgToDb.Where(`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I also noticed that before, but I'm unable to figure out how to solve it. I'm noob in asp.net. Any idea how can I solve it?

Comment: Without knowing your table/schma/entities, how can i help ?

Comment: @Shyju, please check my updates. I've added the table design snap.

Comment: See the answer I posted with the assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

> but the thread lists is showing each message as a thread

Because that is what you are querying. See this line of code.

```
 db.MsgToDb.Where(a => a.owner_id == getUser.serial).ToList()
```

You are querying the messages. If you want the threads, you should be querying the threads table/entities.

So i would add a new property to your view model for the list of threads.

```
public class ThreadViewModel
{
  public int Id {set;get;}
  public string Title {set;get;}
}
public class InboxViewModel
{
   public List<ThreadViewModel> Threads {set;get;}
   public InboxViewModel()
   {
     Threads= new List<ThreadViewModel>();
   }
}
```

and in your action method,

```
public ActionResult ViewAllThreads(string MsgPanelId)
{
    var getUser = rentdb.OwnerRegs.Where(a => a.username == User.Identity.Name)
                                  .FirstOrDefault();
    var vm=new InboxViewModel();
    vm.Threads = rentdb.Threads.Where(a => a.owner_id == getUser.serial)
                .Select(t=>new ThreadViewModel { Id=t.Id,Title=t.Title}).ToList();

     return View(vm);

}
```

Assuming `rentdb.Threads` returns the collection of Thread entities.

Now your `ViewAllThreads.cshtml` view should be strongly typed to our view model

```
@model InboxViewModel
<table>
 <td><th>Title</th>
@foreach (var item in Model.AllMsg)
{
        <tr>          
            <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.title)</td>       
            <td class="text-center">@Html.ActionLink("View Thread", "Reply", "Home",
                                  new { threadId = item.Id },null)</td>
        </tr>
}
</table>
```

Now to show the messages under a thread, you may query the messages under that thread in your Reply action method

```
public ActionResult Reply(int threadId)
{
  var threads = rentdb.Messages.Where(s=>s.thread_id==theadId).ToList();
  var vm =new InboxModel() { AllMsg = threads };
  return View(vm);
}
```

You may add more null/security checking to this method as needed.